# How to make facebook social plugin fully responsive

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I am using Facebook social plugin for developers on my website. It's not responsive on mobiles and tablets I followed few StackOverflow answers but still not able to solve my issue. I have a content row and and a span6 class in which my widget is placed.

my HTML is like this.

```
<div class="row content_row">
<div class="span6">
<div class="Facebook">
<h2><a id="about_us">Facebook</a></h2>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="400px" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336">iFixandRepair - Wellington</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

i did apply some CSS From other answers but it also failed.

Css:

```
.fb-page, .fb-page iframe[style], .fb-page span {
 min-width: 100% !important; 
 width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: Facebook’s social plugins are for the most part not really responsive. Apart from the configuration options they offer, there’s little you can do about that. For the page plugin it is officially documented, that it will only adapt to the container size on page load, but not dynamically after that if the window gets resized (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#adaptive-width) If you really need the latter, then you have to set up your own resize handler script, that reloads the plugin if necessary.

Comment: my containers are always 100% in width of the screen but i dont know why FB widget dont follow its width..

Answer (score 1):

**Restrictions**

Using CSS3 transform

Set data-adapt-container-width="false"
(or something went wrong under 500px)

This fb-plugin was set to 500x500

```
<script src="jquery.rwd-fb-plugin.js"></script>

<!--FB-page-plugin part1-->
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { ... } </script>

<!--FB-page-plugin part2-->
<div class="fb-page"> ... </div>

$(function(){
    $('.fb-page').rwd();
});
```

Demo: [RWD-fb-plugin](http://kuofp.github.io/RWD-fb-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You need call fb-page div with new data-width and call function "FB.XFBML.parse();" every time, when is site resized.
So JavaScript can help for this problem:

```
<div class="row content_row">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="Facebook">
      <h2><a id="about_us">Facebook</a></h2>
      <div class="facebook-wrap">
      <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="400px" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336">iFixandRepair - Wellington</a></blockquote></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.2";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  $(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $('.facebook-wrap').html('<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336" data-width="'+$('.facebook-wrap).width()+'" data-height="400px"  data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFix-And-Repair/242100755854336">iFixandRepair - Wellington</a></blockquote></div></div>');
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your answer but its not working fine it some times give right results but on page loads some times it fails

Comment: Use my script in $(window).resize(function() and also without .resize(function():
  <script>$('.facebook-wrap').html('...'); $(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $('.facebook-wrap').html('...');
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    });
  });</script>